# Google Sheets comma separated numbers in the Netherlands

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets, number-formatting, decimalformat

I made a form in Google Sheets with JavaScript. With that form I write data to a sheet and make calculations that are also written to the sheet. The data are numbers with decimals. In the Netherlands, decimals are separated with a comma. The entered numbers are initially neatly written with a comma to the sheet. The calculation is just wrong. There the numbers are treated as if the decimal point is a thousand separator. When the same (entered) numbers are read again by the form, the comma is also regarded as a separator between thousands and Sheets places a dot and 000 at the end of the number. This causes it to be given a complete mess. I know it has to do with the difference between US and Dutch number formats but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and was able to solve it? Or someone willing to look for a solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem since in Serbia it is the same and I have used this little function to make all of my data into point decimal separator.

```
function toPointSep(n) {
    'use strict';
    n = n.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

You can use the above function in order to get the data calculated correctly and then make a similar function transferring from point separated decimals back to comma separated decimals.